# How does a spring's maximum compression ratio change with decreasing it's free length for a coiled helical spring(compression)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I'm just looking for a simple expression formula for how maximum spring compression changes with free length of a coiled helical spring, say a Compression spring.

A way of understanding what I mean by maximum spring compression - the point before a permanent set occurs in the spring. Another way of looking at it is Deflection as a % of Maximum Deflection . So maximum compression is expressed as a fraction or decimal.

So say all other aspects of the spring remain constant - coil pitch, inner outer and mean diameter, modulus of rigidity, elasticity, material, etc.

If you cut a spring down, spring constant(spring rate) $K$ is inversely proportional to spring free length $L$, as expressed by : $K_\text{new}L_\text{new}=K_\text{orig}L_\text{orig}$.

Simply put, if you cut a spring lengthwise, what happens to the Maximum Compression ratio?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for maximum relative change in length that does not break the spring, right? I.e. when $L$ is the length of the spring and $\Delta L$ the maximum change in length, we're interested in $\frac{\Delta L}{L}$?

The maximum change in length that does not break the spring would depend on the stress that change in length creates in the given material and with the given spring geometry. I.e. you can only compress a spring reversibly until a yield stress is reached. Now, given a material law we can have a direct relation between stress and strain. The strain will scale like $\frac{\Delta L}{L}$, i.e. there will be a one-to-one relation between the maximum stress the material can take and the corresponding relative compression $\frac{\Delta L}{L}$. The latter, in conclusion, does not depend on the total length of the spring.